# tcpreplay removing IP checksums?

Tags: tcp, ip, checksum, tcpdump, scapy

I have a packet trace that I forge with `scapy` and resend with `tcpreplay`. I recompute IP and transport-layer checksums with `Scapy`, save the packets to disk on `pcap` file and call `tcpreplay` on it.

By running `tcpdump` in parallel I noticed that all **IP checksums** of those outgoing packets have no value at all. It seems that `tcpreplay` is removing it each time.

Now, does this happen on purpose? Am I missing something?

Checksums should be correct, so  I don't think `tcpreplay` removes them because a check on it failed.

Comment: does those packets are received by the receipt with the correct checksums?

Comment: I didn't get your question. The packets were correctly received at the receiver, so I'm not /too/ worried. It's just that tcpreplay, when applied to a packet trace where each packet has a correct Ip checksums, seems to be removing such checksums.

Comment: if you use sendfast in scapy it uses tcpreplay out of the box. Usually if you have checksum issues the best thing to do is just delete them. Scapy should fix it automagically when sending.

Comment: Scapy, when it comes to sending and receiving, is a source of all sorts of problems. I'm so happy now that I'm using my own implementation of `sr`. No more delays of the order of tens of seconds, no more *negative* round trip times, matching of packets is now correct even for duplicate packets, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify the actual tcpreplay command you are using, but tcpreplay **never** edits packets.  You can use tcpreplay-edit or tcprewrite to edit packets, but not tcpreplay.  And even then tcpreplay-edit/tcprewrite will calculate/fix your checksums; not zero them out.

Have you opened up the original pcap generated by scapy in Wireshark and verified there are actually checksums there?  Honestly, this sounds like a simple case of garbage in, garbage out.

FWIW, I'm not aware of anything that would zero out your checksums... at least I can't imagine why the kernel would do that for packets sent via the PF_PACKET interface- that would be a bug IMHO.

If you figure it out, let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As for the tcpreplay command I use, I simply do `tcpreplay --pps=$myPacketRate --intf1=0 $dumpedTrafficLocation`. In the exchange of messages I had with Davide Berra in the other answer I got, we worked out that, due to `offloading`, something for sure happens between the moment I launch `tcpreplay` and the instant in which `tcpdump` captures my outgoing traffic. So, if it's not `tcpreplay` that removes the checksums, could it be the kernel itself? Or the network card?

Comment: OK, I'll inspect the pcap file with wireshark and will get back to you.

Comment: I think the traffic dumped in $dumpedTrafficLocation was captured before the NIC updated the checksum.

Comment: Yes, if you captured the traffic on a system which has checksum offloading enabled, then the outgoing packets sent by the operating system won't have the checksums- they'll just be zero.  Hence tcpdump/wireshark capturing the traffic will capture traffic w/o a checksum.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure about what's going on but i suspect that `tcpreplay` detect that the interface is going to use to send out the packet has the `Offload Checksum` active and let the `NIC` to calculate the right checksum.

Try to disactivate the offload checksum with

```
ethtool -K eth0 rx off tx off
```

then retry and let us know

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I wouldn't want to mess up anything in my system. Since I'm not familiar with `offloading`, how would the above command affect the usability of my machine? Also, I can't seem to find the difference between `rx-checksumming` and `tx-checksumming`. Any idea?
In any case, here's what my options are when I run `ethtool`:
`rx-checksumming: off [fixed]
tx-checksumming: on
 tx-checksum-ipv4: off [fixed]
 tx-checksum-ip-generic: on [fixed]
 tx-checksum-ipv6: off [fixed]
 tx-checksum-fcoe-crc: off [fixed]
 tx-checksum-sctp: off [fixed]
`

Comment: It seems like you have the Checksum Offloading activated for the outgoing packets. It means that IP checksum will be calculated by the NIC hardware instead of by the software. Since tcpdump capture the packets BEFORE they're sent out by the NIC, then the checksum is not already been calculated. If you have the chance to dump the data from the receipt point of view, you can discover what's going on.

Comment: All packets given to `tcpreplay` already have a correct checksum, so it seems that it is indeed `tcpreplay` that removes it and lets the NIC handle it. I can't dump packets at the receiver, but since my packets have a low ttl value, I inspected the payload of the ICMP packets I get back and they all contain a correct checksum value. So yeah, something was indeed working behind the scenes, otherwise I wouldn't have gotten anything back.One more thing I couldn't understand from `ethtool`: is there any difference between `rx-checksumming` and `tx-checksumming`? What do `rx` and `tx` stand for?

Comment: In any case here's what I got when I ran the command above:
`$ sudo ethtool -K eth0 rx off tx off
   Cannot change rx-checksumming
   Cannot change tx-checksumming
Could not change any device features
`  I guess my NIC doesn't allow many changes.

Comment: in rx case, the NIC **verify** the checksum, in tx case the NIC **calculate** the checksum. Look at this infos by Intel: [Intel NIC infos](http://www.intel.com/support/network/adapter/pro100/sb/CS-029402.htm#ico)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this issue using the `tcpreplay-edit` which is included in the same package that `tcpreplay`, in particular this option:

```
-C, --fixcsum              Force recalculation of IPv4/TCP/UDP header checksums
```

Desactivating the offload checksum of the interface is a non sense: when the packet goes out it would be rejected by the next machine having checksum checking enabled (+99%)